# OS X - Is there a way to switch keyboard input languages using keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard, language

Rather self explanatory, but I was hoping to be able to quickly change input languages, without going up to the top and switching manually, rather with a keyboard input? Maybe I'm just too lazy, but I was wondering if this was possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default keyboard shortcut is

```
⌘ + space
```

If you have an application already using this keyboard shortcut it will be disabled. you can check in your keyboard input settings.

[image]

Just select them and if it brings up a warning change them by double clicking on the listed shortcut.